# Rails 5.2 and Sidekiq 5: Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm trying to deliver e-mails with Sidekiq and `deliver_later`.

In my `config/sidekiq.yml` I have:

```
:verbose: true
:concurrency: 25
:queues:
  - [mailers, 7]
  - [critical, 6]
  - [default, 5]
  - [low, 4]
```

In my worker I try do do it with:
`Buyer::OffersMailer.instant_for_published_offer(info_to_deliver).deliver_later`

I see in Sidekiq admin panel my mailer job is stuck in "Retries" with this error:

```
Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25
```

My app can send `deliver_now` e-mails, which I believe rejects assumption that something could be wrong with SMPTP Any ideas, what could be wrong?

**Update**
In addition emails are not delivered in Production, where my config looks like this:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "https://myapp.com" }
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "https://myapp.com"
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'myval',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => 'myval',
  :password       => Rails.application.credentials.mailgun_smtp_pass,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Probably, you have your `config.action_mailer` misconfigured. It seems it tries to send mail to `localhost` via STMP (port 25).

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk Looks like, however `deliver_now` works ok. In addition it doesn't work in production with my SMPTP settings - please, see in my Update above.

Comment: `deliver_now` sends email in *the Rails* process, while `deliver_later` does this in *the Sidekiq* one. So, highly likely, you have wrong configured _environment_ for the Sidekiq. Test `Rails.env` both in the Rails and the Sidekiq processes. They should be same.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk Looks like you are right. When I did in my production console `bundle exec sidekiq -e production` it did work. Now the big question is, why my Procfile with `main_worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e production` is not working?

Comment: It's another question which depends on how is your production configured.

Answer (score 0):

Since your emails are sent correctly using `#deliver_now` method, this means that your Mailer config is just fine. Now that aside you should have this in your `application.rb` config file:

`config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq`

and in `config\initializers\sidekiq.rb` you need to have Redis URL to be configured:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: (ENV["REDIS_URL"] || 'redis://localhost:6379/0') }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: (ENV["REDIS_URL"] || 'redis://localhost:6379/0') }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in production was due to environment settings in Procfile. As of [Sidekiq docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#environment) in my case worked `RAILS_ENV=production`

So my working procfile looks like this:

```
main_worker: bundle exec sidekiq RAILS_ENV=production
```

Don't forget to scale your worker if you're using [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#scaling-the-number-of-dynos) or [Dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/process-management/#psscale-command).